# Redux reducers initializing same state key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm messing around with the ['simplest-redux-example' on github](https://github.com/jackielii/simplest-redux-example) and I've added a second reducer that decrements state.count.  If I have the increment and decrement reducers in a switch case statement, it works fine.  The exercise I wanted to perform was to split reducers into as many modular pieces as possible.  This code throws an error saying that count is undefined.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';

// React component
class Counter extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const { value, onIncreaseClick, onDecreaseClick } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{value}</span>
        <button onClick={onIncreaseClick}>Increase</button>
        <button onClick={onDecreaseClick}>Decrease</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Action:
const increaseAction = {type: 'increase'};
const decreaseAction = {type: 'decrease'};

// Reducer:
function counter(state, action) {
  let count = state.count;
  switch(action.type){
    case 'increase':
      return {count: count+1};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
function decrementer(state, action) {
  let count = state.count;
  switch(action.type){
    case 'decrease':
      return {count: count -1};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  counter,
  decrementer
})

// Store:
let store = createStore(rootReducer, {count: 0});

// Map Redux state to component props
function mapStateToProps(state)  {
  console.log("mapStatetoProps heyyyy");
  return {
    value: state.count
  };
}

// Map Redux actions to component props
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  console.log("mapDispatchtoProps heyyyy");
  return {
    onIncreaseClick: () => dispatch(increaseAction),
    onDecreaseClick: () => dispatch(decreaseAction)
  };
}

// Connected Component:
let App = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Counter);

React.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    {() => <App />}
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: At what line it states that?

Comment: at the let count = state.count in the counter function.

Comment: And have you tried to `console.log(state)`?

Comment: yep... it's undefined

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reducers passed to `combineReducers` get different *pieces* of the state object.

> The resulting reducer calls every child reducer, and gather their results into a single state object. **The shape of the state object matches the keys of the passed `reducers`.**

(Emphasis mine)

So, the internal state object would look like

```
{
  counter: result of passing `state.counter` into counter reducer
  decrementer: result of passing `state.decrementer` into decrementer reducer
}
```

This is analogous to having separate stores in a flux application, where each store both operates its own "piece" of the global app state.

Since you actually want these two reducers to work on the *same* portion of the state object, you actually want something more like [reduce-reducers](https://github.com/acdlite/reduce-reducers), though it's very easy to implement yourself—just pass the state into each reducer in turn, reducing the initial state with the new state from each reducer.

In fact, it's so simple, the implementation is just a few lines:

```
export default function reduceReducers(...reducers) {
  return (previous, current) =>
    reducers.reduce(
      (p, r) => r(p, current),
      previous
    );
}
```

and your `rootReducer` would be

```
const rootReducer = reduceReducers(counter, decrementer);
```

Comment: thanks!  reduce-reducer is a great tip.  I was eventually able to see that my state was actually `state = {counter: {count:0}, decrementer: {count:0}}`

Answer (score 7):

You're so close!  The catch is that when you use combineReducers it actually splits the "state" such that the states of the reducers you feed in are properties on the "state" object.

As such, in order to feed them default parameters as follows:

`let store = createStore(rootReducer, {counter: {count: 0}, decrementer: {count:0}});`