# How does each reducer get their own part of state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently learning Redux after get some React fundamental concepts, i am watching Learn Redux video series from Wes Bost which is an amazing resource!

I have the next question, in that tutorial we have a store with:

- Posts
- Comments

Comments

It is suppose to every "part" of the store should have a "reducer", so we have also "comments" and "posts" reducers which are merged inside index reducer with combineReducers. Everything is okay until now, but here my question comes:

Let's say i have the Comments reducer, it receive state and action, but their state matches with state.comments. Same happens with Posts reducer, how the state shape matches with the a specific part of the state?

This is from Redux doc:

> Note that each of these reducers is managing its own part of the global state. The state parameter is different for every reducer, and corresponds to the part of the state it manages.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674767/redux-reducers-initializing-same-state-key Probably it answer my question, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combineReducer` does that part of the magic. 
This that invokes every reducer inside the passed all the reducers object, and builds a state object with the same shape.

As per their [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html):

```
As your app grows more complex, you'll want to split your reducing 
function into separate functions, each managing independent parts of the
state.

The combineReducers helper function turns an object whose values are
different reducing functions into a single reducing function you can pass to 
createStore.
```

Answer (score 1):

That is part of Redux design. The reducers manage their own state. The root reducer combines the state of individual reducers. There is just a single store in Redux which has the combined state.

Answer (score 0):

The reducers act based on `action.type` . Depending on the `type` you change part of the state. They dont know automatically. e.g. :

```
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        visibilityFilter: action.filter
      })
    case ADD_TODO:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        todos: [
          ...state.todos,
          {
            text: action.text,
            completed: false
          }
        ]
      })    
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking *how* Redux matches a reducer with its part of the state, you may find the answer reading the Redux CombineReducers code here:

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/combineReducers.js

Around line 147 you see that each reducer is applied to its key of the state.